# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Getting this for contains()

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in list_variant:
    if df2['ProductName'].str.contains(i):
        df2["Variant_ind"] ='Y'
    else:
        df2['Variant_ind'] = 'N'
```

I have a list of variant items, I am trying to find if that list item is present in the product name description or not!

Comment: Please see this and edit the above code. [How to insert code properly on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

pandas.Series.str.contains returns a series hence the error you are not comparing each value in the `df2['ProductName']` to contain `i` you can either use lambda functions in apply to solve this or use the returned mask to set `df2["Variant_ind"]`

```
for i in list_variant:
    mask = df2['ProductName'].str.contains(i):
    df2["Variant_ind"] = numpy.where(mask, 'Y', 'N')
```